# Stack Exchange Sites Acting Weird

Tags: support, search

At 4:36AM UTC On 11/9/13 (Approx. Timestamp: 1383971294), search is acting weird for me.

When I try to search for something, it takes 20-30 seconds to load, and then reports that there were no search results found.

[image: Imgur]

So, since I had nothing better to do at the time, I wrote this post.

After logging out and logging back in, it fixed the problem (or maybe it was fixed while I was logging in and out). I was also unable to ask a question but was able to browse the site. I am posting with the hope that someone will look into this (I was brought to a page stating that an error was reported), as I would not want it to happen again to anyone.

Comment: The whole site went a bit weird for a few minutes. I wasn't able to upload any images into chat or a post. "Failed to upload image; couldn't reach imgur"

Comment: @Mysticial Same here.

Comment: I can't login using OpenID on my other accounts as well

Comment: seems to be fixed now.

Comment: My inbox is also empty

Comment: @UV-D Log out and back in

Comment: hmm no change, it probably is a cache thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was some [maintenance](https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/66398678030/database-upgrades-nov-9th-2013) going on Nov 9 around that time:

[image: tweet]